# Use CMake execute_process in Msys environment

Tags: bash, cmake, mingw, msysgit

I'm trying to execute a script from `CMake` after building a library, in the `msysgit` environment, in order to update the `PATH`.

The lines of code in question:

```
set(SCRIPT_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/script")
if(MINGW)
  set(COMMAND "source ${SCRIPT_DIR}/mingwpath")
else()
  # Other script. In this case, CMake won't enter here.
endif()

set(PATH_DIRS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

execute_process(COMMAND ${COMMAND} ${PATH_DIRS}
                RESULT_VARIABLE r
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE o
                ERROR_VARIABLE e
)

message(STATUS ${COMMAND})
message(STATUS ${PATH_DIRS})
message(STATUS "RESULT: ${r}")
message(STATUS "OUTPUT: ${o}")
message(STATUS "ERROR: ${e}")
```

and the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$1:$PATH
```

yet I always end with this result:

```
source D:/test/src/script/mingwpath
D:/test/build/

RESULT: System can't find the specified file.
OUTPUT: 
ERROR:
```

The thing is that if I type that exact command in the terminal, it works.

If instead of running the script, I try to run `ls`:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ls
              RESULT_VARIABLE r
              OUTPUT_VARIABLE o
              ERROR_VARIABLE e
)
```

I get the same output message as before.

I also removed the `source` in the command call, and ended up with this `result` message:

```
%1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Executing directly the script from the terminal works.

Answer (score 0):

From the [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) on `execute_command()`:

> CMake executes the child process using operating system APIs directly. All arguments are passed VERBATIM to the child process. No intermediate shell is used [...]

Since `source` is a shell built-in (and cmake isn't firing up a shell) it won't get found on the filesystem as a command .  So remove the "source" statement and instead call your script directly:

```
set(COMMAND "${SCRIPT_DIR}/mingwpath")
```

**Caveat:** I tested this on Linux, not MinGW, but that said the initial symptom was the same at least.

Comment: I already did that before posting the question. It didn't work.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, sorry.  I'll nuke this answer

Comment: One other thought - if your CMake is a Win32 application it won't know what a shell script is at all - what if you rewrote your `mingwpath` as a batch script? e.g.  `SET PATH=%1;%PATH%` ?

Comment: Hi! I'm using the CMake gui, so yes, that's a Win32 app. But it's using the `MinGW` compiler and `make` will be invoked from the `msysgit` environment.